# Does Google crawl content inside HTML5 template tags?

Tags: html, templates, seo

HTML5 template tags are meant to be completely inert as if the content doesn't exist in the source but is that the case when Google crawls and then indexes a webpage?

Does anyone have any data that can prove one way or another that Google indexes or doesn't index content within template tags? Template tags are great but I don't want to use them if they adversely affect SEO

Comment: Interested in this as well especially since angular 2.0+ uses <template> for the asterisk expansion syntax (*ngIf, *ngSwitch, *ngFor). Would be cool if you got some SEO benefits from it.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced something today that would confirm it does affect SEO.

I just received a warning from the Google Search Console about increasing 404 errors, and almost all URL in error are in that form: `/some-path/some-page/$%7Bconsent.infoURL%7D`.

Once URL decoded, we can see that `${consent.infoURL}` is a variable I use in a template tag, on a `href` attribute:

```
<template data-template="cookie-notice">
    `<div data-cookie-notice class="cookie-notice" role="dialog">
    <span class="cookie-notice-caption">${consent.captionText}</span>
    <a class="cookie-notice-link" href="${consent.infoURL}">${consent.linkText}</a>
    <button data-button-consent type="button" class="cookie-notice-button">${consent.buttonText}</a>
    </div>`
</template>
```

So Google Bot indeed follows links in `template` tags.

Comment: I have seen Google crawl URLs from data-attributes and JSON - I will now add html5 templates to the list. I believe Google crawls ANY url it can find, but this may not relate to SEO. What I really want to know is: Do the keywords inside html5 template tags get indexed the same as the main page content?

Answer (score 5):

I was curious about this as well, as I was thinking about using the `<template>` tag as a form of server-side rendering or pre-rending some content that would be updated via AJAX/JS once the page is ready.

I checked the [Google Webmaster Tools Structured Data Tester](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) to see if it would read [microdata](http://html5doctor.com/microdata/) out of HTML tags that were placed inside the `<template>` tag.

[image: google structured data template tag test]

As you can see from the screenshot, it does seem to read the data that is inside the `<template>` tag. I wouldn't consider this a verified answer, but it does suggest that the parser (at least when it comes to HTML microdata) doesn't ignore content inside `<template>` tags.

Comment: This seems to suggest Google does read content in html5 template tags, however it is not 100% proof. Perhaps I need to setup an experiment by adding a unique, made-up keyword in an html5 template tag and then see if the page ranks for that keyword. If it does, then that would be a 100% yes.

Comment: @MatthewJamesTaylor I wonder if you ever got to finding a definitive answer on this

Comment: @teleaziz I never did find out. It would actually be pretty simple to create a test: Just include a completely unique word within a template tag and after Google's indexed the page search for it to see if the page comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I was looking into the same thing and found that instead of the `<template>` tag you can use a `<script>` tag with the type of `text/template`...

```html
<script id="example" type="text/template">
    <div data-cookie-notice class="cookie-notice" role="dialog">
      <span class="cookie-notice-caption">${consent.captionText}</span>
      <a class="cookie-notice-link" href="${consent.infoURL}">${consent.linkText}</a>
      <button data-button-consent type="button" class="cookie-notice-button">${consent.buttonText}</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

And this is not readable by Google as far as I am aware